# Join Columnar Strings

Tags: code-golf, string

Write the shortest possible program or function that will join a list of columnar strings.

For this challenge, columnar strings are defined as one-character-wide strings **spanning across multiple lines**. Each character, except for the last one, is **separated by a newline character**. Some examples, separated by `---`:

```
a
b
c
d
---
h
e
l
l
o
---
c
o
d
e
 
g
o
l
f
---
"
q
u
o
t
e
s
"
```

Given a list of columnar strings, join them into a single string with multiple columns. If the columnar string is longer than its surroundings, it should be left-padded by spaces.

#### Notes

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!
- You may assume inputs are ASCII only.
- You may have trailing newlines.
- You may have trailing spaces.
- This is **not a transpose challenge**; each string in the input list of strings has newlines separating each character. The ["multi-line strings vs list of strings as input"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/17095#17095) default does not apply here; each string in the test cases are separated by `---` and include newlines.

#### Test Cases

```
Input:
---
a
b
c
d
---
h
e
l
l
o
---
c
o
d
e

g
o
l
f
---
"
q
u
o
t
e
s
"
---
Output: (note how `hello` and `code golf` are left-padded by spaces)
ahc"
beoq
cldu
dleo
 o t
  ge
  os
  l"
  f


Input:
---
h
w
---
e
o
---
l
r
---
l
l
---
o
d
---
Output:
hello
world

Input:
---
p

f
---
b
m
v
---
t

s
---
d
n
z
---
k

x
---
g
N
h
---
Output:
pbtdkg
 m n N
fvszxh

Input:
---
1
---

2
---


3
---



4
---
6



5
---
Output:
1   6
 2
  3
   4
    5

Input:
---
a

c
---
|
---
b
d
---
Output:
a|b
  d
c

Input:
---
Output:
(empty output, or single newline)
```

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25352/77309)

Comment: Can we output as a list?

Comment: @Steffan if the output lists are row-wise, yes. (e.g. in the "hello world" case, would output `[hello, world]`)

Comment: You should probably specify that a row can be empty and not a space (if that's intentional, that is)

Comment: @hakr14 perhaps this part requires clarification from OP: "columnar strings are defined as **one-character-wide strings** spanning across multiple lines." Does the one-character-wide specification extend to "empty" lines (i.e. use a space) or not (i.e. no space)?

Comment: @MamaFunRoll good point actually. My assumption stems from the test cases, since they contain "properly" empty lines, but this could be an oversight. My vote is for clarification.

Comment: @MamaFunRoll cc hakr14 the 1-character-wide extends to empty lines only if they contain a space before the newline, otherwise there can be an empty string before the newline

Comment: Can you output an array instead of text?

Comment: @jdt ideally output should be a string, but you can use a list of chars, list of bytes, list of strings, etc

Answer (score 10):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, 39

Input is taken from files; 1 file per column; filenames passed as command-line parameters.

```bash
paste $@|expand|sed -r 's/(.) {7}/\1/g'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY6xDsIwDET3@woLIRWGNCogsVSIBVZ@gCVtQjtUpeAgVaJ8e3AJQ@Tl7Hs@uzLchtp4OlCR@9FTWdLpcoZBhRoWs472JrVbOHRS9wTYpkAtlhWI0IjqcEvAXQou8MBLEC8wSzfPwM6TUv@P4uGY/ltFGAx7R8vj5MbB9HZiZ0k9KWO9ytf03n/0tdBNFsIX)

Comment: Nice. I looked at [`pr`](https://tio.run/##TY6xDsIwDET3@woLIRWGNCogsVSIBVZ@gCVtQjtUpeAgVaJ8e3AJQ@Tl7Hs@uzLchtp4OlCR@9FTWdLpcoZBhRoWs472JrVbOHRS9wTYpkAtlhWI0IjqcEvAXQou8MBLEC8wSzfPwM6TUv@P4uGY/ltFGAx7R8vj5MbB9HZiZ0k9KWO9ytf03n/0tdBNFsIX) and [`lam`](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKdgqFdSUaJgY6Pg6u/GlciVxJXMlcIFYkOkjZClM7hSuXKAMB9JgTGygmSgVApQkQJXOpCVw5WGpNAEWaESVyFXKVBJCVBxMZAHEuMqTi1R0NWFughiMcR0sFau/zmJuQoqDv//AwA) but could not coerce them to work as required.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 8 bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix function, taking list of strings with CR as newline.

```apl
⍉∘↑⎕FMT¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU7LSgNBELz7FWEuq@AeNOoPCBIFI7i52TmsSTYBVzdW4ltPSvDBBD0IfoIHwYv5gXxK/8haM@NBFobp6urq6kqHedy9SvOiX5Zqn/TxQydvOn3f2m3NP8tMJ6837FjUzmr68lALXRzHd4tqp/p8r/ZL7c/8ux4Wk/1N/q3GdrJUZk69k@w1owOTCg4FHUHXLJuBoCfI/SvYky448ayg7zuOMo7ECE4FZ54be8WIImPa0cJ/f1peUN4LhlxGKDmL867qh@6SO8BUx4JzorGjRgQMciK4Jjpy1CUBMzUFg6rLikuIVf8L6n9VsEa0EaBgXVDdSx3foeg2JKjGa0e/)

`¨` for each string:

`⎕FMT` ForMaT as character matrix, evaluating control characters for layout

`↑` mix into 3D array (layers: number of strings; rows: hight of longest string; columns: 1)

`∘` then:

`⍉` reverse order of axes (layers: 1; rows: hight of longest string; columns: number of strings)

---

### Pre spec-change solution, 2 bytes

```apl
⍉↑
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Fv56O2if/THrVNqH7UNxVIPerdqvCou0UBwtPV1a3VeNTb96ir@VHvmke9Ww6tNwZqAEoGBzkDyRAPz2DN/2kKj3pXHVqhnpiUnKKuoJ6RmpOTD6ST81NSFdLzc9KAbKXC0vyS1GIldS6Y4oxyoHAqSF1OEYjIARL5KQj5AgWQvqTcMiBZolAMJFPyqoBktkIFkEz3y0AoNQQKKBiBCAVjMKlgAqTMgLSpAkJVokIyULQGZCjYGgP9R11NQCl1dQA)

Comment: This is not a transpose challenge; each input string has newlines separating each character.

Comment: @bigyihsuan Per default input/output rules, [submissions may use list of strings instead of multi-line strings](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17095/43319). My function takes multi-line strings as matrices, which are equivalent to lists of strings.

Comment: However, that completely disregards the intentions of the challenge: to join multiple, many-lined strings.

Comment: A row can be empty. Check the test cases: there are no spaces

Comment: @bigyihsuan OK, the new solution follows the new spec.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 9 bytes

```
↵¤ðvVðÞṪṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwi4oa1wqTDsHZWw7DDnuG5quG5hSIsIiIsIlsnMScsJ1xcbjInLCdcXG5cXG4zJywnXFxuXFxuXFxuNCcsJzVcXG5cXG5cXG5cXG42J10iXQ==)

Comment: In the TIO link, the inputs look as if they're regular strings, rather than columnar strings (characters separated by newlines...)...

Comment: This is not a transpose challenge; each input string has newlines separating each character.

Comment: @bigyihsuan So we can output as a list, but not input as a list?

Comment: @Steffan You can input as a list of strings (that contain newlines). You can input as a list of lists of characters. If your language doesn't support lists, a delimited string is allowed.

Comment: Ah, I see. Fixed.

Comment: Wait, so if we input as a list of lists of characters, then does it still need to contain newlines?

Comment: @Steffan yes, since newlines are also characters

Comment: [Fails with concurrent or leading newlines](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwiMnbhuJ7DsMOe4bmqIiwiIiwiWycxJywnXFxuMicsJ1xcblxcbjMnLCdcXG5cXG5cXG40JywnNVxcblxcblxcblxcbjYnXSJd)

Comment: @hakr14 Fixed, thanks

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>1</s> 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Note that the spec states that "... *columnar strings are defined as one-character-wide strings* ...", so any empty lines in the test cases should contain a space character.

```
Õë
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&header=cVKyaS2zMSlt%2bg&code=1es&input=IjEKLS0tCgoyCi0tLQoKCjMKLS0tCgoKCjQKLS0tCjYKCgoKNSI) (header allows for input to be formatted as per the test cases) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&header=cVKyaS2zMSlt%2bg&code=1es&footer=VrdpVLDO51KzaS2zszE&input=WwonYQpiCmMKZAotLS0KaAplCmwKbApvCi0tLQpjCm8KZAplCgpnCm8KbApmCi0tLQoiCnEKdQpvCnQKZQpzCiInCgonaAp3Ci0tLQplCm8KLS0tCmwKcgotLS0KbApsCi0tLQpvCmQnCgoncAoKZgotLS0KYgptCnYKLS0tCnQKCnMKLS0tCmQKbgp6Ci0tLQprCgp4Ci0tLQpnCk4KaCcKCicxCi0tLQoKMgotLS0KCgozCi0tLQoKCgo0Ci0tLQo2CgoKCjUnCgonYQoKYwotLS0KfAotLS0KYgpkJwoKJycKXS1t)

```
Õë     :Implicit input of array of multi-line strings
Õ      :Transpose
 ë     :Remove every second element
       :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Comment: I don't know Japt or the input format, nor what `-R` or `U.y()` do, but the input has to be a list of *columns*, not plain strings.

Comment: This is not a transpose challenge; each input string has newlines separating each character.

Comment: [Fails with concurrent or leading newlines](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=1es&input=WwonMScKJwoyJwonCgozJwonCgoKNCcKJzYKCgoKNScKXQ)

Comment: @hakr14, from the spec "_columnar strings are defined as one-character-wide strings_". So the empty lines in your example should have a single space character.

Comment: In comments under the question: "the 1-character-wide extends to empty lines only if they contain a space before the newline, otherwise **there can be an empty string before the newline**"

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ε¶¡1ú€θ}ζ
```

Input as a list of multiline strings; output as a list of list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3NZD2w4tNDy861HTmnM7as9t@@91aPf/aCVDJR2lmDwjMBmTZwylY/JMgCwzCDMmz1QpFgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##RU67TsNAEOz5CmvrowivAglFlFAgeq8LxzlIFLM29jnEUdLwJ/S0WAg60/sj@BEzdxsJ6XQ7Mzs7u0WdzpZ2XNONlI27jMi05oiuM9ekeVQ0TsVpOw4ffde/TX6@fl/fh8/90I1XdF9Z59rjslqKs/N/u7ntv03fTcc4ppRlxpKxzMnQgsWy5OEV4JALdKCCPAaCzgMIE8szSxM0F8ZqFiZKTBT7nBeYrKZgpNKSo/hAdZUYCGE44IllDeS8VANgJ9AWaOWlje6/Y1no7MTfICfhZzk9VJYzoAuFLOfqTT3O0NjprsN6SpI/). (The footer in the single-TIO is to join each inner list of characters; and then each string by newlines. Feel free to remove it to see the actual list output.)

**Explanation:**

```python
ε       # Map over each multiline string of the (implicit) input-list:
 ¶¡     #  Split it on newlines
   1ú€θ #  Convert empty strings to spaces:
   1ú   #   Pad each inner character with a leading space
     €  #   Map over each inner 1 or 2-char string
      θ #    Only keep its last character
}ζ      # After the map: zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns, using " " as filler
        # character if the lists are of unequal lengths
        # (after which the resulting matrix of characters is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>123 121 137</s> 128 bytes

```python
def f(l):l=[''.join(c or' 'for c in q.split('\n'))for q in l];[print(*x,sep='')for x in zip(*[s+max(map(len,l))*' 'for s in l])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BDoMgEETv@xXEC4tVL7218UusBypQaRAQaKL9eYu2SbPJ7s6bZMavaXT2vG1CKqLQsItpO0qbp9MWB@ICJVS5QAaiLZmb6I1OSG@WMrbjecemv3Y@aJuwXKoofUvpYS67@dYeyy6eJr7gxD0aaSvDWPnLjd8A1m968i4kEtcICvNuYhLaNkFygexfXNf10b5xuMMAAjKAESSYPO5QQ74iEwKP/BlQBy1ghlfWKTsRig8)

+16 bytes because it was failing for concurrent newlines (@hakr14)

Saved 9 bytes by using a trick from 97.100.97.108's answer where it outputs a lot of newlines at the end.

Comment: Taking input as regular strings seems to be completely ignoring the description of the challenge: "columnar strings are defined as one-character-wide strings spanning across multiple lines"...

Comment: Your first answer is not what this challenge is asking for. This is not a transpose challenge; each input string has newlines separating each character.

Comment: [Fails with concurrent or leading newlines](https://tio.run/##RY5BDsIgEEX3nIIdM7WQaNWFpiepXTQpRAwCBRatl0famriYeS/5k8n3S3o62@Q8SkUVGLyZtmNMvJy2MInojU7AHpYhKhfoRLWlpr93PmiboJrrKH3L2BbOa/jRHqouHuA9zGU8GGlrg8gLISJWjLL1OO6fsM/67V1INC6RKChbxDRqK4IcRsB/A875ViMfSVFCTjtI8yM5b3Jd9fIF)

Comment: @hakr14 I've changed it but I'm not sure exactly what OP is looking for... [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7NDoMgEITvPAU3dq2YtLY9tPFJrAfjT0qDgMBB@/IU1KSH3fkyk@yOWf1bqzKEfhjpCBIfsqoZKz5aKOiotoyyUVvaUaHoXDgjhQf2Ugwx2XOyZfOsjRXKQ7bkbjAVY1u4pPArDGS1O8HULnEMyEHlEpFHBYeYHQ/cfgmbICajradudWSEuAvne6EKO7Q94L8B53yrEc4kIiGXXUh5KLlucE94@wE "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Looks good to me

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, <s>13</s> 61 bytes

*+48 bytes in order to properly account for newlines in columnar strings (@hakr14)*

```
@(b)reshape(strrep(b(:,1:2:end)',char(10),' '),[],size(b)(1))
```

Takes in columnar strings (with newline between characters), used as follows:

```
f = ans
a = ['a' newline 'b' newline 'c' newline 'd';
'h' newline 'e' newline 'l' newline 'l' newline 'o';
'c' newline 'o' newline 'd' newline 'e' newline newline newline 'g' newline 'o' newline 'l' newline 'f';
'"' newline 'q' newline 'u' newline 'o' newline 't' newline 'e' newline 's' newline '"']
f(a)
```

Comment: Fairly sure the "space" in `"code golf"` is meant to be an "empty character", i.e. `''`, in which case this fails.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 6 bytes

```
ＦＡ«Ｐι→
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nck7DsIwEATQmjmFlca2BBeAE1DQ0EYpjPOxpVU2GDsN4uzLNtFKo5m3MYUSOZDIzMW4@7q16rw3X5wejWreSl6ry/6mm/fJXZ95SVXnT6TvrbUBL0SM2s5GI2EC6fEBEYxREYsWwnx4hzeaUtXfB53KMMhlpz8) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input in JSON-like format (but with Python string delimiters). Explanation:

```
ＦＡ«
```

Loop over all of the input strings.

```
Ｐι
```

Print the string to the canvas without moving the cursor.

```
→
```

Move the cursor one character to the right.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>77</s> 95 bytes

*+18 bytes in order to properly account for newlines inside of the columnar string (@hakr14)*

```python
lambda l:"\n".join(map("".join,zip(*[s[::2].replace("\n"," ")+" "*max(map(len,l))for s in l])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BDoMgFET3noKwASxx0W4aE08iLACh2nw/FG3S9vJWdDOZSWZeJn3XMeLtnvIWOrWBme1gCLRUIW2ecUI@m8Tp6eVvSrzul75tr7rJPoFxnpeqpISKyy71bD7HBDxKECLETBYyIQEthNhM1zNj3cAkYaMHiMW4OHiFjwihJPp6x9UvlOnK7m2F7PzhDpYrLKOrlCdceeB2h/4B)

Takes in lists of columnar strings (characters separated by newlines). Exploits the rule that you can have extra whitespace at the end.

Comment: [Fail with concurrent or leading newlines](https://tio.run/##LYzBDsIgEER/hewJKjFpq8aQ@CXQA0aJmGXZ0B60P4@k9TLzDm@Gv8sr03jlUsPNVfTp/vACDTiC4ztHksmzhJ31Gll2drbGDNMBBHTJfzYBn6RRqZCLmEUkgZNSqnKJtMggLfSg2@OwpaPx345OjS47OjpDW9Uf)

Comment: @hakr14 I would assume that's not a valid columnar string?

Comment: The provided test cases would disagree

Comment: @hakr14Ql Ah, my bad, I thought there was a space.

Answer (score 2):

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 51 bytes

```
"""."fold
over0:"."" "\ /#" ""."zip~
"^$"" "\ /# ++
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-sclin) Takes input as a list of lists of single-character strings, and outputs as a list of row-based strings.

For testing purposes (`c<>` splits each string into a list of single-character strings):

```
["abcd" "hello" "code golf" "\"quotes\""] c<> ; n>< n>o
"""."fold
over0:"."" "\ /#" ""."zip~
"^$"" "\ /# ++
```

### Explanation

Prettified code:

```
"""."fold
over0:"."" "\ /#" ""."zip~
"^$"" "\ /# ++
```

- `"" \; fold` starting with the empty string, fold over each column...

  - `over 0: "." " "\ /#` get string of spaces with length of row built thus far as *x*
  - `" " ; zip~` zip with the following (placeholding *x* for empty accumulator elements and a single space for empty subsequent elements)...

    - `"^$"" "\ /#` replace empty string with space
    - `++` concatenate

Comment: Fails if a "character" is empty, which would represent an empty row in an input string. e.g. `[["1"] ["" "2"] ["" "" "3"] ["" "" "" "4"] ["6" "" "" "" "5"]]`

Comment: @hakr14 should be fixed, thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 25 bytes

```
j%2.t:R"(?<=\n)\n|^\n"+;b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P0vVSK/EKkhJw97GNiZPMyavJi4mT0nbOun/fyVDJR2lmDwjMBmTZwylY/JMgCwzCDMmz1QJAA)

Could save 2 bytes if [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) supported alternations in lookbehinds.

###### Explanation:

```
j%2.t:R"(?<=\n)\n|^\n"+;b  | Full program
j%2.t:R"(?<=\n)\n|^\n"+;bQ | with implicit varibles
---------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
      R                  Q | For each string in the input,
     :                     |  Replace
       "(?<=\n)\n|^\n"     |   Each newline preceded by another newline or by the start of the string
                      +;b  |   with " \n"
   .t                      | Ragged transpose
 %2                        | Every other item (removes the newlines)
j                          | Join by newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

## Excel 65 bytes

```
=LET(v,TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(A:A),"-"),MID(v,SEQUENCE(MAX(LEN(v))),1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Excel (ms365), 120 bytes

[image]

Formula in `A1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,MAP(SEQUENCE(ROUND(MAX(LEN(A2:A5))/2,),,,2),LAMBDA(a,LET(b,MID(A2:A5,a,1),CONCAT(IF(b=""," ",b))))))
```

I do know that since you allow for trailing spaces I could remove `ROUND()` and `/2` but it felt like cheating.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>139</s> 124 bytes

- -15 bytes thanks to ceilingcat and jdt

Takes wide character strings as input.

```c
f(*s,**t,m,i){for(t=s,m=0;i=*t;)m=fmax(wcslen(*t++),m);for(;i<m;i-=~puts(""))for(t=s;*t;t++)putchar(i<wcslen(*t)?i[*t]:32);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU9BTsMwELz3FZZPceJIpQUOuBYfqPhA3UNIm8Yi3pTapRUlPJ2w2WKEUKJVNDs7M7su87IpYNdbCMwVFpK31m4Eu0wYQypN/Wqth4axZOhXa3FZ8sLAs4HSwIZLtuS1ga2BhqolBkctTolnBnbU4rSiqeEGXg0ciQ0k8gYMx@G0k/@XYfqJbNuYjkGHCBoC7fWUEfeeDrjuxZtdDAvEe8J4Jxh4J/xC/Jkwnv1koB4PviEJamcRYM3/YKxbau9ji3U3HlbQsCT5R7x19EWRmOK/kyxN06AmiKv2kATtFcOehSyTbH8MPuGaPi4EuaokDUJNuh6Bl@iVTlpx@TFLp6fKakwQTleuOCen0jdbQFOWCemEGoTKLpyyuf68LsDouBuNgxD5si4OiV382sWjXaVh/TCfCdX1/VdZNcXO9/mpzxv3DQ)

Comment: Building on @ceilingcat, [124 bytes](https://tio.run/##bU9BTsMwELz3FZZPceJIpQUOuBYfqPhA3UNIm8Yi3pTapRUlPJ2w2WKEUKJVNDs7M7su87IpYNdbCMwVFpK31m4Eu0wYQypN/Wqth4axZOhXa3FZ8sLAs4HSwIZLtuS1ga2BhqolBkctTolnBnbU4rSiqeEGXg0ciQ0k8gYMx@G0k/@XYfqJbNuYjkGHCBoC7fWUEfeeDrjuxZtdDAvEe8J4Jxh4J/xC/Jkwnv1koB4PviEJamcRYM3/YKxbau9ji3U3HlbQsCT5R7x19EWRmOK/kyxN06AmiKv2kATtFcOehSyTbH8MPuGaPi4EuaokDUJNuh6Bl@iVTlpx@TFLp6fKakwQTleuOCen0jdbQFOWCemEGoTKLpyyuf68LsDouBuNgxD5si4OiV382sWjXaVh/TCfCdX1/VdZNcXO9/mpzxv3DQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 45 bytes

```javascript
x=>[...x+x].map((_,i)=>x.map(v=>v[i+i]||' '))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCoMwEEX3cwrpJglq6LJQdOkFulSpaRJtSppoomLBu9tBZvH/ex/mI1YRZTDjnDuv9FEVx1aUNed8S7eWf8VI6TMzrCi3E9aiXGuTmnbfSUIYO@4gvYveam79QCsa9LSYoCnpI2E8aKEqY/Xj5yS9ZmSZ@xvqOFozd43L87xxHX4R8AIJClDAGzRYPH@SxFRoEhiwWehPe4EJFuQZlwiXPw)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 43 bytes

```javascript
x=>[...x+x].map((_,i)=>x.map(v=>v[i]||' '))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxBDoIwEEX3cwripm2ExqWJKUsu4BKI1FKwprZAgdSEu@OEhZnFn/dm8t9ylUFNZpgz51u9F2KPIi855/Eca/6RA6WP1DCRxwNWka@lqbeNJISx/QbKu@Ct5tb3tKCTHhczaUq6QBiftGwLY/X96xS9pGSZuyvqMFgzN5XLsqxyzVGrRK7@vmHYLOEJClrAJ3iBBovjD1KYLZoEetwsdIc9wQgL8oyXAKcf)

43 take input as array, which looks unallowed so I added the 45